# Getting the current user's path rather than application path in java

Tags: java, file, command-line, java-io, filepath

I am trying to get the current users path in a giant command line application that has multiple dependencies. Every time a "." is used, it gives me the application path (where the jar exists), rather than the current user path(where the call is being made).

So, when this is ran:

```
File file = new File(".");
System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
```

Gives me the path that the application exists in.

But when I create a separate small application, and use the same code. Call the jar from a different directory, it gives the current user path.

I am using JSAP command line parser for the command line arguments, its acting the same way. How can this be solved? I want my big application to get the current user path, not application path.

What would cause them to behave differently?

Comment: By _current user path_ you mean the location, from where the user starts your app, i.e. where he calls `java -jar ./path/to/app/app.jar`?

Comment: yes, I want the directory of where the user is calling the jar file. It seems to work in a small standalone app. Not the big app, even though I inserted the code the 1st line of the main of the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll find that the batch file (/shell script) which launches your "big application" is changing directory to the main jar file's directory before kicking off Java, which is why your simple test application returns the user's working directory for `new File(".")` while the big app returns the jar file's directory.

Try storing the user's CWD early in the batch file and then passing it to Java:

```
set savedcwd=%cd%
... later on ...
java "-Dsavedcwd=%savedcwd%"
```

then in your application

```
String savedcwd = System.getProperty("savedcwd");
```

Comment: You are right, do you know if its possible to change the batch file such that it will behave as if the application is called directly from the user directory and not where  batch file is located? I am using a command line parser, that I don't have code for. The file path is used in many different command line arguments, in different positions. I prefer not to change any java code.

Comment: There's probably a reason why the batch file changes directory to the jar file's directory.  If you change the batch file to NOT change directory to the jar file's directory, you'll probably break something else.  It's now a question of what's easier to fix: the Java code which wants `"."`==Current_Working_Directory or the batch file / Java code which wants `"."`==Main_JAR_dir.  `"."` can't point to two things at once.  It's one or the other.  Also AFAIK you can't change the value of `"."` once the JVM has booted, it needs to be set up via the .bat/.sh (`cd`) before `java` is run.

Comment: I just looked at the issue again, I can't find where the directory is being changed in the shell script. Sorry, this is all new for me, trying to learn! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Find where 'java' is invoked in the big application's batch file, and on the line right before `java`, put the command: `echo cwd=%cd%` and on the line after that (but still before `java`) put `pause`.  Then the batch file will tell you what the CWD is right before launching java.

Comment: I understand that, only thing I am confused about is that the script looks straight forward. I don't see any modifications of the cd or cad I looked at another command line app with a similar script and it seems receive the correct working directory. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry about that, I see where the problem is. Thanks a lot for your help. I was being a little stupid as well. Now I can focus on writing java code!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mindspring.com/~mgrand/java-system-properties.htm

you want "user.home" property, like

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String currentDir = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
OR
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

Comment: getAbsolutePath(); gives me the same path.

Answer (score 0):

1) As stated above, if you want to get "current directory", one way is to use `File(".").getAbsolutePath()`

2) If you want to get the user's $PATH variable (or *any* environment variable), use `System.getenv()`:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html